# Ninject with a base controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, ninject

I am wondering how do you do constructor inject with ninject 2.0 when you have a base controller?

I have

```
        private readonly IBaseService baseService;

        public BaseController(IBaseService baseService)
        {
            this.baseService = baseService;

        }


Bind<IBaseService>().To<BaseService>();


public class OtherController : BaseController
{
        private readonly IOtherService otherService;

        public OtherController(IOtherService otherService, IBaseService baseService) 
        {
            this.otherService = otherService;
        }
```

Yet I get

> 'BaseController' does not contain a
>   constructor that takes 0 arguments

Comment: I too had this problem, but it smelt awful to me to force all my child controllers to provide the dependency for the base controller.  I started with that approach, then refined it so that the base controller fetched an instance of the Ninject Kernel explicitly to resolve it's dependencies.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to inject both services into your `OtherController` and call the base constructor passing the service it requires:

```
public OtherController(IOtherService otherService, IBaseService baseService)
    : base(baseService) { this.otherService = otherService; }
```

Comment: hmm so if your inheriting you have to do it like this? You can't get it to bind the new object sort of like how if it was not inheriting would work?

Comment: @chobo2 ignoring dependency injection, but looking at inheritance... if a base class requires a service, it is the responsibility of the inheriting class to provide that. Otherwise the base type cannot be initialised correctly.

Comment: Best practices or not, I'm not going to pull in the dependency on each controller that uses the base controller. In my constructor of the base controller I'm going to manually resolve it (which is basically the same thing). `DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(typeof(ICustomerService))`

Comment: @LéMuffinMan I can see why you want to do that to make your API simpler, but in terms of testability, you're hiding complexities that aren't exposed through your public API. If it is only you working on the code, fair enough, but working with a team of developers, they may not have intimate knowledge that your subclassed controller requires a dependency provided by service location (using `DependencyResolver`), which may not be available or configured in a test scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to chain through to the base controller, no?

```
public OtherController(IOtherService otherService, IBaseService baseService) : base(baseService)
```