# managing ISession in base controller...

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-2, ninject

I am avoiding injecting in my ISession into every controller, thus avoiding this: [Ninject with a base controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720806/ninject-with-a-base-controller)

I am trying to access my IRepository inside my base controller so i could use it throughout my app, is there any problems with managing the lifetime of the object using the second method below? Basically I only want to create it again every time I need it per action request...

//Using Ninject to inject...

```
 private readonly IReadOnlySession _repo;
    public SimpleController(IReadOnlySession repo)
    {
        _repo = repo;
    }
```

//Get from Base controller -> my preferred method...

```
public abstract class AbstractBaseController : Controller
{
  public AbstractBaseController() { }

 private static IReadOnlyGenericRepository readonlysession;
 public static IReadOnlyGenericRepository ReadOnlySession
 {
   get { return (readonlysession ?? (readonlysession = new ReadOnlyGenericRepository())); }
 }
}
```

//Then access using

```
var detail = ReadOnlySession.Single<Cat>(x=> x.CatID== _catid);
```

IReadOnlyGenericRepository simply inherits from:

```
public interface IReadOnlySession
    {
        T Single<T>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression) where T : class, new();
        System.Linq.IQueryable<T> All<T>() where T : class, new();
    }
```

Update: Declaring the code below in my AbstractBaseController, can unit testing be achieved?

```
private IReadOnlySession readonlysession;
public IReadOnlySession _repo
{
   get { return (readonlysession ?? (readonlysession = GetReadOnlySession())); }
}

protected virtual IReadOnlySession GetReadOnlySession()
{
  return new ReadOnlyGenericRepository();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also introduce a fixed dependency to `ReadOnlyGenericRepository`. And I in my opinion the unittests and implementation both will be much less understandable/readable. Personally, I think this solution gives you more and worse negative points than what you win by not having to add a single constructor parameter (Which is done by a simple Alt-Enter in Resharper anyway).

Positive:

- No constructor argument required (Or to say it differently: Saves a single Alt-Enter strike in Resharper)

Negative:

- Fix dependency to `ReadOnlyGenericRepository`
- Requires a testclass overriding `GetReadOnlySession()` for each controller
- Less understandable unittests and implementation

Also think about aggregation instead of inheritance in case there is more you have to pass to the base constructor.

Comment: it gets more complicated than that. Anyway, Yes a fixed dependency exists - but as you noted you can override, as I have a abstract base controller - it can very easily be overridden in one place and nowhere else. Can we say it is still less understandable??? Is that not a preference for a developer to use Composition over inheritance?

Comment: the problem comes when I require multiple Interfaces, I am always injecting, passing onto my base controller, could we not say in those scenarios benefits do arise?I mean especially if the behaviour can be overidden anyway...

Comment: I think in this scenario something is wrong in first place. If you need to pass so many interfaces to the base inheritance probably isn't the best solution. As you said think about composition instead. Also check if the single responsibility principle is fulfilled. In most cases where injection is complicated there is something wrong with the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any problems with managing the lifetime of the object using the second method below?

Unit testing your controllers in isolation might be a little hard with this static object in the base controller. Also I don't know what is this `IReadOnlySession` supposed to represent but because it is static it will be shared among all users => all requests, so you should ensure that it is thread-safe, ... Personally I prefer the repository approach which is being injected into the controllers through a DI framework.

Comment: Is there a way to overcome this? How can I refactor? How would I make it threadsafe?

Comment: @Haroon, by using the first method and by configuring your DI framework to instantiate a new session for each controller => basically tie it up to the HTTP Request. With Ninject for example you could use the `.InRequestScope()` when configuring the container.

Comment: If I wanted to avoid DI only for my IRepository??? I am still going to to use Ninject for services as long as it is not repository...

Comment: @Haroon, no unit testing is till difficult because you don't have a setter for the _repo property meaning that you cannot substitute it with a mocked object in the unit test. It will always use the real `ReadOnlyGenericRepository` that you have hardcoded in your controller. On the other hand because the property is no longer static at least you will not have problems with multiple threads.

Comment: But could I not override the GetReadOnlySession() method for testing? therefore I provide my own concrete class, one that does implement IReadOnlySession? That was the reason why I made it virtual???

Comment: @Haroon, indeed. I didn't notice that you declared this method as virtual. But this would mean that everytime you want to test some controller you will have to write a test controller inside the unit test overriding this method and invoking the actions on this test controller instead of the actual controller. It will work but could be cumbersome.

Comment: Thanks, this controller is part of the basecontroller so I am only ever going to override in one place! :P